# React development server not reflecting changes made using vite, what could be the issue?

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, vite

I'm building a react app, and when I run **npm run dev** for the first time, everything works fine, but when I make changes to my component that should appear on the UI, it doesn't auto-refresh. I even tried refreshing manually, but it didn't take the changes. But when I stop the server and re-run **npm run dev**, it takes all the changes I made.
There's no error in the terminal.
I have tried creating my app using CRA but no changes. What could be the problem?
I'm using WSL (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS) on my Windows 11 device

Comment: There could be many problems. You will have to post a more specific question to get help. Error messages in the console? Error messages in the terminal? OS/Browser/Node/CRA versions? Etc.

Comment: Are you using CRA or Vite? They are both very different. If it is CRA then  you need ot use the `start` script, it doesn't come with a dev script.